# Debugging Dispose method of IDisposable In Component With LifeStylePerWebRequest In Castle Windsor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, idisposable, castle

I am  writing an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I am using Castle Windsor as my DI container. I have a couple of components that implement IDisposable and have a lifestyle of LifeStylePerWebRequest. These components only depend other components with LifeStylePerWebRequest. The components are managed by the container. I want to debug the implementation of the Dispose method at the end of a web request however, it seems that my break points are not getting hit in my Dispose(I am using VS2010). What is likely to be the problem?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Dispose()` is not invoked because instance of `YourPerWebRequestType` has not been resolved by IoC.

IoC creates an instance of the type if it is needed only.

When you register a type with lifestyle 'LifeStylePerWebRequest' it does not mean that it is created every web request.